# Needs help for understanding for python code

Tags: python

```
dictLength = len(newDict['SrchResults'])
```

Hi guys, i would like to know what does this ['SrchResults'] mean. what does it do?
I do understand that len(newDict) Gives the total length of the dictionary for newDict.

Comment: take the debugger or the python console and see what 'newDict' is. The use of len() is obvious. Or?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dictionary[key]` is how you access the value of a given dictionary. For example, if I had:

```
newDict = {'SrchResults':['one', 'two', 'three']}
```

Then `newDict['SrchResults']` would return `['one', 'two', 'three']`.

Then `len()` gets the length of the value of the key `'SrchResults'`

Comment: @user2799617 I'm trying to be nice

Comment: In my case Im looking at a python file passed to me from a friend, Im totally new to python and this is my first time looking at it.

A Dictionary was defined to load some json content from an API.
and followed by dictLength = len(newDict['SrchResults'])

Felt kind of confused on the usage of 'SrchResults'

Comment: @user2833545 So `'SrchResults'` is a key in the dictionary. Doing the syntax above gets the value